# Запрос на разных языках не возвращает значение

Tags: python, python-3.x

Заметил такую особенность: если мы в проверке указываем варианты на разных языках, то результаты получаются разные.

Почему??

```
def cur(c):
    z = 810
    y = 826

    if c == ("РУБ" or "RUB"):
        return (str(z))
    elif c == ("БФ" or "GBP"):
        return (str(y))


print(cur("РУБ"))         #will: 810
print(cur("RUB"))         #will: None
```

Comment: Посмотрите с чем вы сравниваете: `print(("РУБ" or "RUB"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Вы не проверяете оба элемента.

Сначала исполняется конструкция `('РУБ' or 'RUB')`, которая возвращает только `'РУБ'`, как первый логически истинный элемент.

Поэтому Ваше первое условие выглядит так:

```py
if c == 'РУБ':
```

*Замените на:*

```py
if c in ('РУБ', 'RUB')  # if c == 'РУБ' or c == 'RUB'
```

*Спасибо за подсказку с использованием `in` участнику [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu).*

Comment: мне кажется в данном случае лучше / лаконичнее использовать ` in (...)`

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!)))))))))))))